# Clickable modifier doesn't work with Card in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I was developing some app in jetpack compose, and I get into the issue of trying to add an onClick event to some custom component and doesn't works, due to the onClickk method is not been called.

Here the way I'm try to add the on click:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun DashboardScreen(
    context: Context,
    navController: NavController,
    dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel,
    authViewModel: AuthViewModel,
) {

    val list = listOf(
        DashboardItem(R.drawable.baseline_payment_24, context.getString(R.string.sellTitle)),
        DashboardItem(R.drawable.baseline_credit_score_24, context.getString(R.string.preCheck)),
        DashboardItem(R.drawable.baseline_money_24, context.getString(R.string.price)),
        DashboardItem(R.drawable.twotone_list_alt_24, context.getString(R.string.list))
    )

... some code

Theme {
Column(
   verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
   modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp)
            ) {
                LazyVerticalGrid(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(end = 16.dp),
                    columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    items(list.size) { index ->
                        DashboardComponent(
                            item = list[index],
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(paddingValues)
                                .background(Color.White)
                                .clickable {
                                    setOnClick(
                                        list,
                                        index,
                                        context,
                                        dashboardViewModel,
                                        navController
                                    )
                                }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

private fun setOnClick(
    list: List<DashboardItem>,
    index: Int,
    context: Context,
    dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel,
    navController: NavController,
) {
    when (list[index].title) {
        context.getString(R.string.sellTitle) -> {
            dashboardViewModel.setIsPreCheck(false)
            navController.navigate(Screens.Sell.route)
        }

        context.getString(R.string.preCheck) -> {
            dashboardViewModel.setIsPreCheck(true)
            navController.navigate(Screens.Sell.route)
        }

        context.getString(R.string.list) -> {
            navController.navigate(Screens.TransactionList.route)
        }

        context.getString(R.string.price) -> {
            navController.navigate(Screens.ListProducts.route)
        }
    }
}
```

here is my UI which do nothing:

[image]

I've found the onClick event is not been called when I try to debug the app, so I guess this solution doesn't work.

Do you know some way to add on click into a list of components which actually works.

Thanks in advance !

[EDIT]

Add DashboardComponent.kt

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DashboardComponent(
    modifier: Modifier,
    item: DashboardItem,
) {

    CepsaStandaloneAppTheme {
        Card(
            modifier = modifier
                .size((LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp)/3),
            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                containerColor = Color.White
            ),
            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(8.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(10),
        ) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            ) {
                Column(
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                ) {
                    Icon(
                        painter = painterResource(id = item.icon),
                        contentDescription = "icon",
                        tint = PrimaryColor,
                        modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp)
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = item.title,
                        color = PrimaryColor,
                        fontSize = 24.sp
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Solution]

Finally I get into a working solution adding a Box around the content of my Card in DashboardComponent, and passing the onClick as argument:

DashboardComponent.kt

```
@Composable
fun DashboardComponent(
    modifier: Modifier,
    item: DashboardItem,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {

    CepsaStandaloneAppTheme {
        Card(
            modifier = modifier
                .size((LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.dp)/3),
            colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
                containerColor = Color.White
            ),
            elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(8.dp),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(10),
        ) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .clickable { onClick.invoke() }) {
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                ) {
                    Column(
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(id = item.icon),
                            contentDescription = "icon",
                            tint = PrimaryColor,
                            modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp)
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = item.title,
                            color = PrimaryColor,
                            fontSize = 24.sp
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code of DashboardComponent

Comment: I think in clickable { } you should use navController.navigate to the next screen, then initialize dashboardViewModel from that screen. You can pass the index as parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `clickable` modifier is applied to `Card`. `Card` delegates to `Surface` and `Surface` effectively disables `clickable` modifier by applying `Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {}` at the end of the modifier chain. You can see that here: [Surface.kt](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/29f2067d2c9446c3f83db76412124652b63bbe02:compose/material3/material3/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/Surface.kt;l=130)
Why? Because applying the `clickable` modifier yourself wouldn't work as expected - `Card/Surface` has a `Shape` that won't be applied to the clickable modifier, so the ripple effect (indication) wouldn't respect rounded corners and it will look ugly. Because of that, `clickable` modifier is disabled and there are overloads for `Card` and `Surface` that have `onClick` argument - you should use these overloads.
So instead of this:

```kotlin
Card(modifier = Modifier.clickable {})
```

you do this:

```kotlin
Card(onClick = {})
```

Comment: I've given a try to your solution, and still doens't work, although thanks for you complete answer.

Comment: Yeah, i am having the same issue. Card(onClick={}) is never called.